# Confused about negation.

Tags: solution-verification, quantifiers

2-3 Weeks ago I had a test, where it wanted the contrapositive of a statement. It wasn't asking for it's truth value.

Original statement in question: There exists x in integers, if x > 1, then where y = 2x + 1 for all y of integers.

But, the answer was

Contrapositive: There exists x in integers, if x <= 1, then where y != 2x + 1 for some y of integers.

Why wasn't the first part changed (There exists x in integers), in a negation, shouldn't everything be changed?

Comment: Not very clear... What is the original statement ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA sorry, i just realized how unclear it was